# Glassfish 3.0.1 memory leak when ran with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows, glassfish, windows-server-2008

I have a memory leak with Glassfish 3.0.1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64bit VPS machine), with or without any running applications

Is there a way to resolve this?

The same Glassfish 3.0.1 work fine on linux and Windows XP SP2 without any leaks.

I can see the leak through the Windows Task Manager. I am using Java SE 6 update 22

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install VisualVM and the GlassFish plugin to verify the memory leak. You can also do some heap dumps and use MAT to analyze the dump and look for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15589.